# X/S flat, X, S regular, but X/S not smooth

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $S$ is the Spec of a discrete valuation domain and $X$ is regular and $X/S$ is flat, but not smooth. What goes wrong in such a situation? The fibres are not geometrically smooth, but what does it mean for $X$?

Answer (score 7):

It means almost nothing for $X$. Take any smooth (projective) variety and project it onto a smooth curve. Very likely the (resolved) map will not be smooth (but it is flat).

For a simple example contemplate
$\mathbb A^2\to \mathbb A^1$ via $(x,y)\mapsto xy$.

Comment: When you base change your example to the DVR at the origin of $\mathbb{A}^1$, how do you see that the upstairs space is still regular?

Comment: The local rings of the base change are local rings of the original.